# What is the 'proper' way to update a react component after an interval with hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using the alpha version of react supporting hooks, and want to validate my approach to updating the text in a component after an interval *without* rendering the component more times than needed when a prop changes.

> **EDIT**: For clarity - this component is calling `moment(timepoint).fromNow()` within the `formatTimeString` function ([docs here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)), so the update isn't totally unneccessary, I promise!

I previously had:

```
const FromNowString = ({ timePoint, ...rest }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(formatTimeString(timePoint));

  useEffect(() => {
    setText(formatTimeString(timePoint));
    let updateInterval = setInterval(
      () => setText(formatTimeString(timePoint)),
      30000
    );
    return () => {
      clearInterval(updateInterval);
    };
  }, [timePoint]);

  // Note the console log here is so we can see when renders occur
  return (
    <StyledText tagName="span" {...rest}>
      {console.log('render') || text}
    </StyledText>
  );
};
```

This "works" - the component correctly updates if the props change, and the component updates at each interval, **however** on mounting, and when a prop changes, the component will render twice.

This is because `useEffect` runs *after* the render that results when the value of `timePoint` changes, and inside my `useEffect` callback I'm immediately calling a `setState` method which triggers an additional render.

Obviously if I remove that call to `setText`, the component doesn't appear to change when the prop changes (until the interval runs) because `text` is still the same.

I finally realised I could trigger a render by setting a state variable that I didn't actually need, like so:

```
const FromNowString = ({ timePoint, ...rest }) => {
  // We never actually use this state value
  const [, triggerRender] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let updateInterval = setInterval(() => triggerRender(), 30000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(updateInterval);
    };
  }, [timePoint]);

  return (
    <StyledText tagName="span" {...rest}>
      {console.log("render") || formatTimeString(timePoint)}
    </StyledText>
  );
};
```

This works perfectly, the component only renders once when it mounts, and once whenever the `timePoint` prop changes, but it feels hacky. Is this the right way of going about things, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It's unclear what's the purpose of this interval. Since timePoint isn't changed over time, it re-renders the component with same data. Please, elaborate on what's the expected behaviour for the component. The preferred way depends on that.

Comment: @estus - sorry, I didn't include that because it's peripheral information that isn't really needed. I've added why I need to update within an edit, see above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this approach seems fine. The main change I would make is to actually change the value each time, so that it is instead:

```
const FromNowString = ({ timePoint, ...rest }) => {
  const [, triggerRender] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateInterval = setInterval(() => triggerRender(prevTriggerIndex => prevTriggerIndex + 1), 30000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(updateInterval);
    };
  }, [timePoint]);

  return (
    <StyledText tagName="span" {...rest}>
      {console.log("render") || formatTimeString(timePoint)}
    </StyledText>
  );
};
```

I have two reasons for suggesting this change:

- I think it will help when debugging and/or verifying the exact behavior that is occurring. You can then look at this state in dev tools and see exactly how many times you have triggered the re-render in this manner.
- The other reason is just to give people looking at this code more confidence that it will actually do what it is intended to do. Even though `setState` reliably triggers a re-render (and React is unlikely to change this since it would break too much), it would be reasonable for someone looking at this code to wonder "Does React guarantee a re-render if a `setState` call doesn't result in any change to the state?" The main reason `setState` always triggers a re-render even if unchanged is because of the possibility of calling `setState` after having done mutations to the existing state, but if the existing state is null and nothing is passed in to the setter, that would be a case where React **could** know that state has not changed since the last render and optimize for it. Rather than force someone to dig into React's exact behavior or worry about whether that behavior could change in the future, I would do an actual change to the state.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, interesting addition - I'll accept this answer soon if I don't meet any resistance to the approach.